# Why doesn't this code insert anything into MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, insert

This code does not work, it doesn't insert anything into the table:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ('../includes/connection.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['titel'], $_POST['indhold'])) {
        $titel = $_POST['titel'];
        $indhold = $_POST['indhold'];
        
        if (empty($titel) or empty($indhold)) {
            $error = 'Alle felter skal udfyldes';
            } else {
                $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO artikler (artikel_titel, artikel_indhold) VALUES (?, ?)');
                $query->bindValue(1, $titel);
                $query->bindValue(2, $indhold);
                
                $query->execute();
                
                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }
    ?>
        <html>
<head>
    <title>Integrere senere</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/billeder/book.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
    <h4>Add article</h4>
    <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#FF0004"><?php echo $error ?></small>
    <?php } ?>
    <br>
    <form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" name="titel" placeholder="Titel">
      <br>
      <br>
    <textarea name="indhold" cols="50" rows="15" placeholder="Indhold"></textarea>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Lav ny side">
    
    
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
    
    
    <?php
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there more code? I don't see where you set a value for `$title` or `$indhold` at all. Also, do you get any error messages? You may need to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? A blank screen? What debugging have you done? Is the INSERT running, but not inserting anything, or is the `if` statement running the `error` part? Have you checked to see if the database is returning an error after you run `prepare()` and `execute()`?

Comment: @andrew It just wouldnt insert

Comment: How do you set value for $titel, $indhold? if can't see any error, add following code at top of your page: <?php ini_set('display_error', 0); error_reporting(0); let us know what error do you get.

Comment: @user3512558 - Then let's get debugging. Both `prepare()` and `execute()` will return a boolean false if they don't succeed. (I'm going to guess that `prepare` is working, as you'd get an error message there, but it's best to be comprehensive). Can you try `var_dump($query)` after your prepare? And can you assign the result of the `execute()` call to a variable, and `var_dump()` that, too?

Comment: @andrewsi "object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(67) "INSERT INTO artikler (artikel_titel, artikel_indhold) VALUES (?, ?)" }" like that

Comment: @EasierNameToReplyTo - excellent, your prepare is working. What about the `execute()`?

Comment: @andrewsi object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(67) "INSERT INTO artikler (artikel_titel, artikel_indhold) VALUES (?, ?)" }